# Changing text of UIButton programmatically swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

Simple question here. I have a UIButton, currencySelector, and I want to programmatically change the text. Here's what I have:

```
currencySelector.text = "foobar"
```

Xcode gives me the error "Expected Declaration". What am I doing wrong, and how can I make the button's text change?

Answer (score 717, accepted):

In Swift 3, 4, 5:

```
button.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
```

Otherwise:

```
button.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Also an `@IBOutlet` has to declared for the `button`.

Comment: You can omit `UIControlState`. e.g. `forState: .Normal`

Comment: Swift3 is now `.normal` note the lower case

Comment: Swift3 change `forState` to `for`

Comment: Swift3: self.btnBuy.setTitle("Buy", for: UIControlState.normal)

Comment: for swift 4 also `button.setTitle("Button Title",for: .normal)` working!, thanks

Answer (score 77):

Just a clarification for those new to **Swift** and **iOS** programming. Below line of code:

```
button.setTitle("myTitle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

only applies to `IBOutlets`, not `IBActions`.

So, if your app is using a button as a function to execute some code, say playing music, and you want to change the title from `Play` to `Pause` based on a toggle variable, you need to also create an `IBOutlet` for that button.

If you try to use `button.setTitle` against an `IBAction` you will get an error.  Its obvious once you know it, but for the noobs (we all were) this is a helpful tip.

Comment: Yep, I was about to google exactly this until I saw your answer.  Thanks! +1

Comment: It is a pattern in IOS that took me a while to discover.  There are attributes of UI items that you have no access to unless an IBOutlet is created.  If ever you are trying to change an attribute of a UI and can't access it, make sure you have both the IBAction that is running some code, and the IBOutlet that provides access to the attributes.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The `sender` of the action will be the button. You can apply anything you wish to the `sender`. You don't need an outlet to do this.

Comment: Neither Bendix answer nor his comment are correct. They are plain wrong.

Comment: The question doesn't mention interface builder so wrong to assume that is the case.

Comment: It also will throw an error warning if you are not updating it in the main thread.  That appears to be new.

Answer (score 19):

Swift 5.0

```
// Standard State
myButton.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 17):

### Swift 5:

```
    let controlStates: Array<UIControl.State> = [.normal, .highlighted, .disabled, .selected, .focused, .application, .reserved]
    for controlState in controlStates {
        button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Title", comment: ""), for: controlState)
    }
```

Comment: I had to use UIControl.State. It said UIControlState was deprecated

Comment: This is unnecessary. If you only set the title for the `.normal` state, then that title will be used for all states.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3:

Set button title:

```
//for normal state:
my_btn.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)

// For highlighted state:
my_btn.setTitle("Button Title2", for: .highlighted)
```

Answer (score 9):

Changing title when attributed is a bit different :

I just ran into a problem : If you have an UIButton with an Attributed Title, you have to use :

```
my_btn.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: my_title), for: my_state)
```

as, per [Apple SetTitle Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle?language=objc) :

> If you set both a title and an attributed title for the button, the button prefers the use of the attributed title over this one.

I had an attributed title and I tried to setTitle on it, with no effect...

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3

When you make the @IBAction:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
  sender.setTitle("string goes here", for: .normal)
}
```

This sets the sender as UIButton (instead of Any) so it targets the btnAction as a UIButton

Answer (score 3):

**swift 4.2 and above**

*using button's IBOutlet*

```
btnOutlet.setTitle("New Title", for: .normal)
```

*using button's IBAction*

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
  sender.setTitle("New Title", for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of 12/12/2021 - Swift version 5.5.1^ assuming you already have an IBOutlet linked to yourButton in a normal state.

```
yourButton.setTitle("Title of your button", for: .normal)
```

Comment: This is already covered in several much older answers.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: view.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.height/2, width: 100, height: 100)
button.setTitle(“Title Button”, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a title for a button in Xcode using swift - 04:
first create a method called setTitle with parameter title and UIController state like below ;

```
func setTitle(_ title : String?, for state : UIControl.State)   {

}
```

and recall this method in your button action method
like ;

```
yourButtonName.setTitle("String", for: .state)
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, in addition to the code, make sure your Title is set to "Plain" not "Attributed" in the Xcode Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5.9

To change the title of a button in Swift, you can access the title property of the button and set it to the desired text. Here's an example:

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
    // Set the initial title of the button
    myButton.setTitle("Initial Title", for: .normal)
}
```

and in IBAction
// Change the title of the button when a certain action occurs
myButton.setTitle("New Title", for: .normal)

In this example, we have a button called myButton. In viewDidLoad(), we set the initial title of the button using setTitle(_:for:) with the .normal control state. Then, in the changeButtonTitle function (which you can associate with a user action, like a button tap), we change the title of the button to "New Title." You can modify the text as needed to change the button's title to whatever you want in response to different events in your app.