# titleLabel?.text dont change ios 10 UIControlState

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to try to change a button title in swift 3 and iOS 10, but it doesn't change. My codes clear, is this a bug ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tel: UIButton!
tel.titleLabel?.text = "+1 123 23 34"

print("tel = \(tel)")
```

> Nothing shows ! And button title doesn't change !

Is this a bug ? Codes looking clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text of UIButton programatically swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326296/changing-text-of-uibutton-programatically-swift)

Comment: @luk2302 i try ios 10 gives error for UIControlState.normal

Comment: then use the correct state, remove the `UIControlState`, read the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I finally found iOS 10 control state working code.

```
tel.setTitle("Button Title",  for: [])
```

I think this will help many people.