# Want to change button title by clicking one of the button in swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have four buttons with tag "1", "2", "3" and "4" . I want to change the title of all buttons when i will click any one of the button. my code is -

```
@IBAction func answerButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {                

    if answerButton.tag == 1 {

    answerButton.setTitle(questionBank.list[questionNumber].answer1, 
    for: .normal)
    } else if answerButton.tag == 2 {

    answerButton.setTitle(questionBank.list[questionNumber].answer2, 
    for: .normal)
    } else if answerButton.tag == 3 {

  answerButton.setTitle(questionBank.list[questionNumber].answer3, 
  for: .normal)
    } else {

  answerButton.setTitle(questionBank.list[questionNumber].answer4, 
  for: .normal)   
    }
}
```

But my code is not working

Comment: You need to add one IBOutlet for each button

Comment: please edit your question and show `answerButton`, `que.answer1`, `que.answer2`, `que.answer3` and `que.answer4` declarations

Comment: *I want to change the title of **all** buttons*. Really? Or do you want to change only the title of the currently pressed button?

Comment: Just remove all `if/else`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your @IBOutlet collection, for example:

```
@IBOutlet private var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Then in your function:

```
@IBAction func answerButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {  

    let answers = [que.answer1, que.answer2, ...]

    zip(buttons, answers).forEach { (button, answer) in
        button.setTitle(answer, for: .normal)
    }              
}
```

Comment: Great idea, I am excited to try it!

Answer (score -1):

//Setting UIButton title

let button = UIButton()

button.setTitle("My Amazing Button", for: .normal)

Please try this.

A similar thread is here too,Hope this will help:

[Changing text of UIButton programmatically swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326296/changing-text-of-uibutton-programmatically-swift)

Comment: You can format your code using: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. This helps others reading your answer.